# Moving .Net Web from Windows 2008 to Windows 2019 and .Net error

Tags: c#, .net

We moved the .NET WEB application from Windows 2008 to Windows 2019 
and we observed the error

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - Loading profiler failed during CoCreateInstance.  Profiler CLSID: '{************************}'.  HRESULT: 0x80040154.  Process ID (decimal): 6880.  Message ID: [0x2504].

That is certain dll file not registered.
But We suspect it is .NET 4.0 - .NET 4.8 changes causing the issue.
We ran the Dependencies Walker and please see the attached screen that it cannot find the files.
We tried to rebuild and didn't work. 
What can we do at this point, thank you[Screenshot of Dependencies Walker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOn6E.png)

Comment: Why are you loading a profiler in the first place?

Comment: The COR_PROFILER I think it is from AWS.  We didn't really set that up.  The Windows 2019 is from AWS EC2.  
What I think that is not related to the missing file which shown in the Dependencies Walker....  Because I removed the profile in environment variable and rebuild the dll still getting same result in Dependencies Walker.

Comment: I doubt that. However, my advice is to figure out what's loading that and take it out of the picture. Profilers can be loaded by setting env variables or I think registry settings too. You'll need to do some more research on the subject.

Comment: The error is due to the VS updater not very robust.  The update fails so the csproj file has wrong versions of the library.  The csproj file is text and you can ope with notepad. I normally create a new project and add the library that is causing issue and then compile to verify the library compiles.  Then open the csproj file with notepad to check version against the project where it is failing.  You can edit the csproj and change version, or delete the reference from project and then add library to update the version.

Comment: A quick GUID search lands on https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/installation/set-up-agents/net-agent-configuration/ So to isolate the culprit, try to deploy a hello world web app first, and then you will see what might be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for Tanveer, Lex Li that I eliminated the error from event log.
I will go thru jdweng to debug why my .NET WEB application still have some weird issues which not related to the event at all